# Decreasing the Size of Mediator

Tags: design-patterns

I am using `mediator` pattern with 10 clients. It happens that the `mediator` class size go beyond three digit numbers. I think it is a bad practice to have such big classes. Is this size an indication of using false design pattern? Do you have any recommendation to decrease the code size of this single mediator? Other design pattern recommendations are welcomed as well.

Comment: How much does your Mediator class know about the clients? Could you add another client without modifying the Mediator class?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau yes, clients are connected through an interface class. So I can add new ones without modifying the actual mediator.

Comment: Do you think we should evaluate code quality by sheer number of lines, _without even looking at the code_?

Comment: @Flater what could I share more?

Comment: @ErdemTuna: Share the code, or short examples of it. Without seeing the code, no judgment can be made. Line count is not a valid measure of quality - though useless line reduction can be a valid improvement. But that requires seeing the code and checking if some of it is indeed unnecessarily long. FWIW, I suspect your code to suffer from OCP (and/or SRP) violations, as the responsibility of a mediator is strictly bounded and should not change based on the number of requests it handles (because that would be an OCP violation)

Comment: @Flater thank you for the detailed suggestion. I will create a short example of the code as soon as possible.